# Use jQuery load() to dynamically load element view

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('body').append('<div id="lang-dialog"></div>');

                $('#lang-dialog').load('URL HERE...');

                $('#lang-dialog').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    autoOpen: false
                });


                $('a#lang').click(function(event)
                {
                    event.preventDefault(); $('#lang-dialog').dialog('open');
                });
```

This makes a link load up a dialog box which is created in the DOM and then will load it's content dynamically using an element view here: `app/views/elements/lang-dialog.ctp`

How do I do this though using CakePHP to spit out the element in the load method of my jquery code?

Thanks

Comment: You need to move the `$('#lang-dialog').dialog(...)` call into a `success` callback of the `.load()` method. Otherwise you will try to create a dialog before the markup is loaded (because `.load()` is asynchronous).

Comment: Can you explain that with a code example please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `$('#lang-dialog').dialog(...)` call into a success callback of the `.load()` method. Otherwise you will try to create a dialog before the markup is loaded (because `.load()` is asynchronous).

> Can you explain that with a code example please?

Certainly.

```
$('body').append('<div id="lang-dialog"></div>');

var $langDialog = $('#lang-dialog')

$langDialog.load('URL HERE...', function ()
{
    $langDialog.dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false
    });
});

$('#lang').click(function()
{
    $langDialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```